# Dynamic NavigationLink SwiftUI Xcode

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

In my HomeView I have 2 cards. I make two new pages (AboutA and AboutB) to be linked to each of this cards.
But if I click on this card I only got preview of first page, because I don't know how to set dynamics navigation for each. This is in my HomeView:

```swift
ForEach(items) { item in
    NavigationLink(destination: AboutA()) {
    CardView(item: item)
}
```

For Card I create "data":

```swift
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var text: String
    var image: String
}
```

Now I need help, what to change in HomeView, and what to change in "data" page.

thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have two cards and you have to show their details in another view, that you call About.
As their nature is similar, I think also About page is really similar or even equal. Maybe the About View it's the same for both the view, so the better thing to do is to create a dynamic About View :

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var text: String
    var image: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State
    var items : [Item] = [Item(title: "A", text: "test text", image: "test image"), Item(title: "B", text: "test text", image: "test image")]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: AboutView(item : item)) {
                    Text(item.text)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AboutView : View {
    var item : Item
    var body : some View {
        Text(item.title)
    }
}
```

So the AboutView has the same structure for both the card, but it will be filled with the right data.
You surely can add some control to understand witch card is it, and edit something in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved my problem with link card to new pages, but I get new problem :)

```
struct HomeView: View {
@State var show = false
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack{
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: AboutH()) {
                            CardView(item: items[0])}
                            NavigationLink(destination: Parkovi()) {
                                CardView(item: items[1])}
                                NavigationLink(destination: Rijeke()) {
                                    CardView(item: items[2])
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
```

Now I have my 3 cards, that are link to pages, but I have tree time in row of same cards :(

Any help?
Thank you.